# what is the use of expand_dims in image processing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I saw a face detection model which consists of the below function. but I could not understand what is the use of the expand_dims function. can anyone explain me what it is and why we are using ?

```
def get_embedding(model,face_pixels):
    face_pixels=face_pixels.astype('float32')
    mean, std=face_pixels.mean(),face_pixels.std()
    face_pixels=(face_pixels-mean)/std
    samples=expand_dims(face_pixels,axis=0)
    yhat=model.predict(samples)
    return yhat[0]
```

Comment: You need to specify what expand_dims function you are talking about, people cannot guess what function is it without context. Imports for example can give some context.

Answer (score 3):

[`tf.keras.Conv2D`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D) layers expect input with 4D shape:

```
(n_samples, height, width, channels)
```

Most libraries that load images will load in 3D like this:

```
(height, width, channels)
```

By using `np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)` or `tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)`, you add a batch dimension at the beginning, effectively turning your data in the 4D format the Keras needs for `Conv2D` layers. For instance:

```
(224, 224, 3)
```

to:

```
(1, 224, 224, 3)
```

If you give `Conv2D` 3D data, it will give something like this:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_19_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28)

Comment: Your answer makes assumptions on what expand_dims function the OP is talking about, it might not be correct.